# How is the best/fastest solution to find string in few columns in table database

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I have tables in the database and there are several text fields in it. In each field entries have from several to several dozens of characters, these are "text" type fields.

I have mysql in version 5.5.XX (it is not possible to upgrade the version). So far, the search was done using the LIKE query, but the amount of data is so large that it is too slow.

The sample query was as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%' OR CustomerLastame LIKE 'and%' OR CustomerCompany LIKE 'a%'
```

How can search process accelerate?
I allow either a solution in mysql or as an external service / tool.

I would like to ask someone who has had and solve a similar problem. Because I have read a lot on the internet, but I'm not sure about the effective way.

Comment: Do you have adequate indexes on the table? Are most most searches `foo%`? Indexes can help. If full wild card, `%bar%`, then not so much. You could look at FULLTEXT search with MySQL or perhaps explore something like Elastic Search.

Comment: MySQL generally cannot take advantage an index when OR is involved. The usual way to avoid this issue is to UNION similar queries (that differ by only which part of the OR they use.)

Comment: Everywhere where the indexes should have been set up. I was wondering about ElasticSearch, but I do not know if it will work if the fields in the fields as I wrote are quite short. With long texts, Elasticsearch would be good, did anyone use this tool for short strings.